# Can we put jenkins artifacts and history to remote server?

Tags: jenkins

I want to put our jenkins master to a vm, but the artifacts&build history are too large, so can we separate our jenkins master and it's build history, and put the build history to remote server? I just want to put a lightweight jenkins master to vm.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Jenkins master on a VM, but I simply add a separate disk for [the `JENKINS_HOME` folder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) (which will include the data: job definitions)

That way, I don't need another remote server, I simply keep the server (in my case, Tomcat + `jenkins.war`) separate from its data, by setting "`JENKINS_HOME`" environment variable to the new home directory before launching the servlet container.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer,  is the separate disk you mentioned a Virtual Disk?  We can store all the artifacts and history to the disk, right?

Comment: @RiddickZhang yes, in my case it is a vmdk (vm virtual disk)

Comment: Yeah, but the service of our company from a different team is so expensive(what a shame :) ), that's why I want to put our jenkins master to cloud, but put jenkins history to a remote physic machine. Is there any way to do this? how about using ssh?

Comment: @RiddickZhang I avoid putting Jenkins on anything but near the source control server: the latency would be too great otherwise. I haven't seen a setup where Jenkins runs with a deported JENKINS_HOME. If your cloud can accommodate both Jenkins and JENKINS_HOME, then yes, you can then declare slaves you access though ssh, and those slave can then be in your local infrastructure.

Comment: oh, I didn't consider the latency, maybe try to use a jenkins plugin to compress the artifacts would be a good idea. anyway, thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @RiddickZhang Sure. By the way, By the way, consider (for this question or your other question) to https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer: that is how this Q&A site works.

Comment: JENKINS_HOME is used for both building and storing artifacts. While former wins from faster disk access, the latter wins from larger disk capacity. So it would be really optimal to say put workspace to SSD and put artifacts on HDD.

Comment: @AlexChe Aren(t the artifacts stored in workspaces created by the Jenkins *agents*? In that case, `JENKINS_HOME` is not relevant, since it is only for the Jenkins master.

Comment: @VonC, you mean, that _if I use agents_, and don't build on Jenkins master, then no build is done in JENKINS_HOME? This way the problem of trade-off between fast and large storage is solved by separating Jenkins master (as artifacts storage) and Jenkins slave (as build machine). Makes sense. I never used agents before, probably that's why this idea never came to my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexChe Yes, that is the idea. I have always had to use agents in enterprises where I had to deploy and maintain a Jenkins service.